# ABS warning light has no issues, but ABS is not functioning

Tags: brakes, hyundai, abs, warning-light

I have a 2013 Hyundai Sonata. I had a hard brake on the freeway the other day where the wheels locked up and I ended up skidding a bit.

My ABS light was not on, and still isn't, but it's clear that something is wrong with the abs system. More confusing to me though, is the light. It does light up successfully when the car starts, so it's not simply a bad bulb. Any ideas what could cause ABS to fail, but not trigger a light?

Comment: I'd start with an OBD code reader, and see what (if any) codes are reported.

Comment: Are your tyres good enough not to skid? Worn tyres drift even ABS works.